# Adding unique elements to an array without auxiliary variable in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, hash

I have an array of hashes like

```
@data_records = [
                 {"user": "user1", "key1": "v1k1", ... , "keyN": "v1kN"},
                 {"user": "user2", "key1": "v2k1", ... , "keyN": "v2kN"},
                 {"user": "user3", "key1": "v3k1", ... , "keyN": "v3kN"},
                 {"user": "user1", "key1": "v4k1", ... , "keyN": "v4kN"},
                 {"user": "user1", "key1": "v5k1", ... , "keyN": "v5kN"},
                 {"user": "user4", "key1": "v6k1", ... , "keyN": "v6kN"},
                ]
```

As you may see, I may have many 'records' for the same user. In the example above, `user1` has three records, for instance.

Now I need, based on this array of hashes, to generate an array with a single entry for every user in it. I mean, I need

```
[ "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4" ]
```

but not

```
[ "user1", "user2", "user3", "user1", "user1", "user4" ].
```

I wrote the following piece of code, which does the job:

```
def users_array
  arr = Array.new
  @data_records.each { |item| arr.push(item["user"]) if not arr.include?(item["user"])}
  arr
end
```

But it bothers me the fact I must use the auxiliary variable `arr` for this to work. I'm sure there is a shorter way to to this with `Array#map` method. Since `Array#map` returns an array, it could be something like

```
def users_array
  @data_records.map { |item| item["user"] if ... }
end
```

The problem is I don't know how to mention the array I'm creating with `Array#map` inside the block. I believe it could be something like

```
def users_array
  @data_records.map { |item| item["user"] if not this.include?(item["user"]) }
end
```

but it doesn't work, of course.

Can someone tell if there is a way to do this?

**EDIT**

Yes, I could use `Array#uniq` to do this. But then I rephrase the question: **Is there a way to refer to the implicit array created by `map` inside the map's block?**

Comment: why not just `@data_records.map { |item| item["user"] }.uniq`?

Comment: yep @data_records.map { |e| e[:user] }.uniq!

Comment: Okay, thanks for both. But I must then rephrase my question. Is there a way to refer the implicit array being created by a map inside its block?

Comment: not with `map`, no; but you could do so with `reduce` or `inject`: `@data_records.inject([]) { |memo, item| memo << item["user"] unless memo.include? item["user"]; memo }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aetherus is the closest to answering your rephrased question and he should get all the credit for pointing out `#each_with_object` to get at the "implicit array." But here's something a little closer to what you're asking:

```
@data_records.each_with_object([]) do |item, this|
  this << item[:user] unless this.include?(item[:user])
end
```

I think using a Set:

```
Set.new(@data_records.map { |item| item[:user] })
```

or `#uniq`:

```
@data_records.map { |item| item[:user] }.uniq
```

will probably be faster and scale to a large number of items better, but I haven't benchmarked it.

Comment: Using an array is part of my requisites, since this method will give its result to another method waiting for an array. But, as you pointed, he deserves the credit for `#each_with_object`. Then I upvoted both answers, but will pick yours as the best answer, for it is closer to what I need.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Most of the time when you say a method is **waiting for an array**, it is actually waiting for an `Enumerable` unless that method access the elements by index. Both arrays and sets are `Enumerable`s.

Comment: Maybe `@data_records.map { |item| item[:user] }.tap(&:uniq!)` is better because it saves some memory :) BTW, this is my favorite usage of `tap`.

Comment: @Aetherus I love that! I frequently want to use the modify-in-place operators but sometimes can't because they might return nil. This is a great technique that I am definitely going to steal. Thanks!

Comment: @Aethenrus, why `.tap(&:uniq!)` rather than `.tap(&:uniq)`? Why not just `.uniq`? Also, `uniq!` returns `nil` if no change was made.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `.uniq` makes a superfluous copy of the data. `.uniq!`, as you've noted, might return `nil`, so it can't be used (at least not without an intermediate step/variable). `.tap(&:uniq)` would make a superfluous copy of the data in a void context and return the original data; in other words, it would be a very expensive no-op. `.tap(&:uniq!)` modifies the data in-place and will always return the de-duped data!

Comment: @mwp, I see. I did a quick benchmark (an array with 10,000 elements, each element a random number between 0 and 999) and `.tap(&:uniq!)` was about twice as fast as `.uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

For me the best way to do this is `each_with_object`, and use a `Set` instead of an array to collect the user names.

```
require 'set'

def users_array
  @data_records.each_with_object(Set.new) do |item, set|
    set << item[:user]
  end
end
```

Comment: The hash pairs are defined like `"user": "user1"`, so `"user"` will actually become a symbol `:user` rather than a string `'user'`.

Comment: @mwp You are absolutely right. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: It was a bug in the OP, so you can hardly be blamed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I fear I may have misunderstood the question.

I will leave my original answer (below), should it be of interest to anyone.

```
def combine(data, key)
  data.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    f = g.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),f| f[k] = (k==:user ? v : [v]) }
    h.update(f[:user]=>f) do |k,o,n|
      o.merge(n) { |kk,nn,oo| kk==:user ? nn : nn+oo } 
    end
  end.values
end 

data_records = [
  {user: "user1", key1: "v1k1", keyN: "v1kN"},
  {user: "user2", key1: "v2k1", keyN: "v2kN"},
  {user: "user3", key1: "v3k1", keyN: "v3kN"},
  {user: "user1", key1: "v4k1", keyN: "v4kN"},
  {user: "user1", key1: "v5k1", keyN: "v5kN"},
  {user: "user4", key1: "v6k1", keyN: "v6kN"},
]

combine(data_records, :user)
  #=> [{:user=>"user1", :key1=>["v1k1", "v4k1", "v5k1"],
  #     :keyN=>["v1kN", "v4kN", "v5kN"]},
  #    {:user=>"user2", :key1=>["v2k1"], :keyN=>["v2kN"]},
  #    {:user=>"user3", :key1=>["v3k1"], :keyN=>["v3kN"]},
  #    {:user=>"user4", :key1=>["v6k1"], :keyN=>["v6kN"]}]
```